# VBA Stop the textbox change event from removing focus from the textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox that filters a listbox containing numbers as the user is typing. What is happening is, after the first number is typed the textbox looses focus and the user needs to click back into the textbox to carry on. It only does it on the first entry once the user has clicked back into the textbox they can keep typing without loosing focus. Is there some way of keeping the focus on the textbox untill the user selects from the listbox?

I've tried to set the focus back to the textbox after the code has run in the change event but no luck.

```
Private Sub tbProjectSearch_Change()

Windows("Dispatch V3.xlsm").Activate

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim i As Long
Dim arrList As Variant

lbProjects.Clear

If ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(tbProjectSearch.Value) <> vbNullString Then
    arrList = ws.Range("F3:F" & ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For i = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
        If InStr(1, arrList(i, 1), Trim(tbProjectSearch.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
            lbProjects.AddItem arrList(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

End If

If lbProjects.ListCount = 1 Then lbProjects.Selected(0) = True
If tbProjectSearch = "" Then Call LoadListProjects

tbProjectSearch.SetFocus

End Sub
```